# Unable to open Sonarqube url in browser

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

```
Sonarqube url:Connection Refused
```

am getting this log while restarting the Sonarqube installed in UBUNTU 16.04.2:

```
app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m 
-Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process7638775371972592569properties
app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process2142955611951444772properties
app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped

 while accessing the url http://myip:9000/sonar,
 Connection gets refused.
```

Comment: There are other logs in that directory. Do they say anything interesting?

Comment: No. The same log is getting updated in soanr.log everytime the sonar gets restarted.

Comment: Can you post web.log, please ?